# Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am trying to execute a selenium program in which I need to download an excel file and read it . I am getting "Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]" as error .can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your file format is xls.
Please change it xlsx and try again